# Kali linux - aircrack-ng - not going into monitor mode

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, drivers, kali-linux

I've been searching for the answer to this for hours and nothing has helped.

I'm trying to enter monitor (promisc) mode in kali and it keeps coming up with errors. I've updated kernels, drivers, etc. and no luck. I think I may have to buy an external wireless device, but want to try here in case a genius can solve my problem before I spend the money. Below is a print out of all the relevant info that should assist (I hope). I'm on a Macbook Pro late 2015.

I have Kali installed as a partition, but I also have the same problem when booting it live from a USB.

```
root@kali:~# uname -r

4.12.0-kali1-amd64

root@kali:~# lspci -nn -d 14e4:

04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM43602 802.11ac Wireless LAN SoC [14e4:43ba] (rev 01)
05:00.0 Multimedia controller [0480]: Broadcom Limited 720p FaceTime HD Camera [14e4:1570]

root@kali:~# iwconfig

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"******"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: ******   
          Bit Rate=24 Mb/s   Tx-Power=31 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-37 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:1  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

root@kali:~# ifconfig

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 288  bytes 22776 (22.2 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 288  bytes 22776 (22.2 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.6  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 *****************  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether *************  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 21851  bytes 23490115 (22.4 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 15106  bytes 1764309 (1.6 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

root@kali:~# ifconfig wlan0 down

root@kali:~# ifconfig wlan0 -promisc 

root@kali:~# ifconfig wlan0 up

root@kali:~# iwconfig

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          **Mode:Managed**  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=31 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:on


root@kali:~# ifconfig

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 816  bytes 61704 (60.2 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 816  bytes 61704 (60.2 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether **************  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 21954  bytes 23496840 (22.4 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 15113  bytes 1765136 (1.6 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

root@kali:~# airmon-ng start wlan0


PHY Interface   Driver      Chipset

phy0    wlan0       brcmfmac    Broadcom Limited BCM43602 802.11ac Wireless LAN SoC (rev 01)


**ERROR adding monitor mode interface: command failed: Operation not supported (-95)**

root@kali:~# ifconfig wlan0 down

root@kali:~# iwconfig wlan0 mode Monitor

**Error for wireless request "Set Mode" (8B06) :
    SET failed on device wlan0 ; Operation not supported.**
```

(Why??)

Answer (score 3):

It seems your network interface not support monitor mode. Try to install another drivers or network interface. Did you install Kali on Virtual Machine?

Answer (score 2):

Since posting this question I have obtained a new wireless dongle which is working just fine. It appears it may have been the AirPort wireless card, which works differently in Mac.  Still don't know why it happened.

Comment: Not all hardware\drivers physically have that capability. Sometimes you need a special driver. Sometimes the hardware can't do it and no driver will fix that. It's best to use a known good adapter, like you did.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your network mode into monitor to activate this feature. Use

```
ifconfig wlan0 down
iwconfig wlan0 mode monitor
ifconfig wlan0 up
```

Try `iwconfig` once again to see if it is changed.